# Найти точки пересечения графиков в c#

Tags: c#, диаграммы, график

У меня есть программа, которая строит два графика, добавляя точки к какой-то встроенной функции построения графика (на выходе должны получиться 2 ломаных кривых). Мне нужно получить узнать точки в которых они пересекаются, и так как эти точки с большой вероятностью не в ходят в список тех, которые я задаю, я не знаю как получить искомое. Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace Stonks
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(double[] price, double[] demand, double[] supply)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series[0].LegendText = "График спроса";
            chart1.Series[1].LegendText = "График предложения";
            chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(price[i], demand[i]);
                chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(price[i], supply[i]);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Применительно к Chart - никак. Это контрол исключительно для визуализации некоторой последовательности данных. Каждый набор точек может отображаться любым из возможных способов, разумеется, совместимых между собой, если они отображаются в одной области. Ни каких вычислений он делать не позволяет.

Если нужно отобразить точки пересечения двух графиков на Chart-е, то эти точки нужно сначала вычислить и добавить в наборы отображаемых точек или дополнительный набор точек, который также потребуется правильно отобразить на Chart-е.